# SQL prepareStatement does not return ResultSet

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I'm facing some odd behaviour with two prepared statements.
What I'm doing is to check if the doument I want to save to the database is present in the current version. If the db not returns an entry I check if there is an older version in db an update it. If nothing is found (not the current and not the older version) I save them as new one.

My code looks like this:

```
try {
    stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4" +
                                                "FROM table" +
                                                "WHERE col1= (SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2= ? and col3= ?) " +
                                                "AND col2= (SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2= ? and col3= ?) " +
                                                "AND col3 = ? " +
                                                "AND col4= ?");
    stmt.setString(1, empm.col1().toString());
    stmt.setString(2, empm.col2().trim());
    stmt.setString(3, empm.col1().toString());
    stmt.setString(4, empm.col2().trim());
    stmt.setShort(5, empm.col3());
    stmt.setShort(6, empm.col4());

    ResultSet stmtResult = stmt.executeQuery();
    // Check if current version is available
    if(stmtResult.next()) {
        Integer existingCol1 = stmtResult.getInt(1);
        String existingCol2 = stmtResult.getString(2).trim();
        Short existingCol3 = stmtResult.getShort(3);
        Short existingCol4 = stmtResult.getShort(4);
        empm.setCol1(null);
        empm.setCol2(null);

        empm.update(connection, "WHERE col1  = " + existingCol1 + " AND col2 = '" + existingCol2 + "' AND col3 = " + existingcol3 + " AND col4 = " + existingCol4);
    } else {
        // Check if older version is available
        PreparedStatement empmHasOlderVersionSql;
        empmHasOlderVersionSql = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4" +
                                        "FROM table" +
                                        "WHERE col1= (SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2= ? and col3= ?) " +
                                        "AND col2= (SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2= ? and col3= ?) " +
                                        "AND col3 = ? " +
                                        "AND col4= ?");
        empmHasOlderVersionSql.setString(1, empm.getPbnr().toString());

        Integer olderVersion = (Integer.parseInt(empm.getCol1().trim())-1);
        empmHasOlderVersionSql.setString(2, olderCol2.toString());

        empmHasOlderVersionSql.setString(3, empm.getCol1().toString());
        empmHasOlderVersionSql.setString(4, olderCol2.toString());
        empmHasOlderVersionSql.setShort(5, empm.getCol3());
        empmHasOlderVersionSql.setShort(6, empm.getCol4());

        ResultSet empmHasOlderVersionResult = empmHasOlderVersionSql.executeQuery();

        // If I found an older version update it with new versions
        if(empmHasOlderVersionResult.next()) {
            System.out.println("Older");
            Integer existingCol1 = empmHasOlderVersionResult.getInt(1);
            String existingcol2 = empmHasOlderVersionResult.getString(2).trim();
            Short existingCol3 = empmHasOlderVersionResult.getShort(3);
            Short existingCol4 = empmHasOlderVersionResult.getShort(4);


            // Update with new versions
            Integer intCol2 = (Integer.parseInt(existingCol2) + 1);
            String newCol2 = intCol2.toString();

            empm.setCol2(newVersion);
            empm.update(connection, "WHERE col1 = " + existingCol1 + " AND col2 = '" + existingCol2 + "' AND col3 = " + existingCol3 + " AND col4 = " + existingCol4);
        } else {

            empm.setCol1(emp.getCol1());
            empm.setCol2(emp.getCol2());

            empm.save(connection);
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    errorMessage = errorMessage.concat("Error while saving entry in empm. ");
}
```

When I have eg. `Col1 = 100` and `Col2 = 1` in DB and in File. Everything works fine.
But if I have in `col1 = 100` and in `Col2 = 2` the code inserts an entry instead of updating to new `Col2 = 2` and `col1` is `null`.

The only difference in the statements executed is the `Col2` value.
Anyone an idea whats possibly wrong?
I' using an `MSSQL2012 DB` and `jtds 1.2.5` with `Eclipse IDE`

**EDIT:**
I finally found out that this is a transaction problem.
When running the application with `connection.autoCommit(true)` everything works fine.
anyone has some tipps on how to set commits or savepoints etc?

Comment: Can you post the code for the object empm, it has an update method on it that might hold a clue.

Comment: The problem already starts by not getting a ResultSet so this part of code isn't executed.

Comment: @Nick sorry. Forgot to mention you.

Comment: Well what happens if you pull the SQL out and run the query in MySQL workbench with the given values?  The reason I ask is col3 and col4 seem to impact the rows being returned.

Comment: I debugged in Sql Profiler and it receives the right values but not returns the result set like i thought